# Не могу получить значение поля при помощи SpEL

Tags: java, spring

При изучении `spring`'а решил реализовать пример из книги. Суть такова: есть класс с инициализированными полями. Есть класс с аналогичными пустыми полями и точкой входа. Есть конфигурационный `xml`-файл, которому с помощью языка `SpEL` передаётся значение поля `name`. Потом класс с точкой входа принимает значение этого поля и выводит на экран. При запуске выдаёт такие ошибки:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'injectSimple' defined in class path resource [SPeL_Testing/spel-config-xml.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'SPeL_Testing' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'SPeL_Testing' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'SPeL_Testing' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Main.class:

```
public class Main {
public String name;
public int age;
public float height;
public boolean programmer;
public Long ageinSeconds;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
    ctx.load("match-arguments.xml");
    ctx.refresh();
    Main simple = (Main) ctx.getBean("injectSimple");
    System.out.println(simple);


}

public String toString() {
    return "Name : " + name + "\n"
            + "Age:" + age + "\n"
            + "Age in Seconds: " + ageinSeconds + "\n"
            + "Height: " + height + "\n"
            + "Is Programmer?: " + programmer;
  }
}
```

InjectSimpleSpel.class:

```
    public class InjectSimpleSpel {
    public String name="Chris Schaefer";
    public int age=32;
    public float height=1.778f;
    public boolean programmer=true;
    public Long ageInSeconds=1009843200L;
    }
```

spel-config-xml.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="injectSimple" class="SpEL.Main"
          p:name="#{SPeL_Testing.InjectSimpleSpel.name}"
          p:age="32"
          p:height="1.778"
          p:programmer="true"
          p:ageInSeconds="1009843200"/>
</beans>
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Я так полагаю `SPeL_Testing` - это наименование твоего пакета, в котором находится класс `InjectSimpleSpel` , но лучше бы было разъяснить этот момент в вопросе. Из этого, я предполагаю, что ты хочешь обратиться к статической переменной класса. Поэтому замени

```
#{SPeL_Testing.InjectSimpleSpel.name}
```

на

```
#{T(SPeL_Testing.InjectSimpleSpel).name}
```

P.S. в java по негласному соглашению имена пакетов не должны содержать заглавных букв и знаков подчеркивания.